# An example for this joint discrete random variable? $P_{X,Y}(x, y) = \frac{4!}{x!y!(4-x-y)!}(\frac{1}{2})^x(\frac{1}{3})^y(\frac{1}{6})^{4-x-y}$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I have been asked to calculate the marginal pdf for the following equation, however, I'm interested to know how exactly would this equation fit in with a word-example?

$P_{X,Y}(x, y) = \frac{4!}{x!y!(4-x-y)!}(\frac{1}{2})^x(\frac{1}{3})^y(\frac{1}{6})^{4-x-y}$

Am I looking for something that counts the differences between two variables when $0 \le x+y \le 4?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you let $Z=4-X-Y$, we have $$P_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = \frac{4!}{x!y!z!}\left( \frac12\right)^x \left( \frac13\right)^y \left( \frac16\right)^{z}$$

where $x+y+z=4$, we can see that this follows multinomial distribution.

Consider four traffic lights where each traffic light is independent. The probability of seeing green is $\frac12$, the probability of seeing amber is $\frac13$. That gives you the probability of seeing $x$ green signals and $y$ amber signals.